# How many objects were created

Tags: java, object

```
    3. class Dozens {
    4. int[] dz = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    5. }
    6. public class Eggs {
    7. public static void main(String[] args) {
    8. Dozens [] da = new Dozens[3];
    9. da[0] = new Dozens();
    10. Dozens d = new Dozens();
    11. da[1] = d;
    12. d = null;
    13. da[1] = null;
    14. // do stuff
    15. }
    16. }

I  have this code from scjp book,which asks how many objects are created and answer was 5 objects ,but i was only able to figure out 4 objects 
1st object -line 4 
2nd object-line 8
3rd object -line 9
4th object -line 10
,can any one explain where and how 5th object is being created?
```

can any one explain where and how 5th object is being created?can any one explain where and how 5th object is being created?can any one explain where and how 5th object is being created?can any one explain where and how 5th object is being created?can any one explain where and how 5th object is being created?

Comment: can you add the explanations for what these four objects are that you identified?

Comment: Why does line 4 create an object? How many objects are created in line 9?

Comment: @Thilo someone edited the code,sorry

Comment: hint: `new Dozens()` creates *two objects*.

Comment: The book is wrong. I see three class objects, one string array, two int arrays, one Dozens array and two Dozens instances. Correct answer is `9+args.length`. Hint: Don't take this comment too serious ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each Dozen class you create two objects:

- Dozen
- dz array

You create 2 `Dozen` objects and one array `da`.

So in the end, we have:

```
2*Dozen+ 3*Array = 5 Objects.
```

If `dz` would be static, than all Dozen instances would share same object reference, but here they don't.

UPDATE:
Objects are created in:

- line 8  = 1 array - with null values
- line 9  = 2 objects (1 Dozer, 1 dz array inside Dozer)
- line 10 = 2 objects (1 Dozer, 1 dz array inside Dozer)

I hope it helps:)

Comment: see edited question ,and please explain in which line number objects are created

Comment: Dozens [] da = new Dozens[3]; this line creates 1 object or 3 objects?

Comment: 1 Object. Because in this way, you create empty array, that has null values. So no more objects are created, beside array.

Comment: if Dozen has method for example method() and you try to execute d[0].method() NullPointer will be returned. The array here as object is not created!!!!!!
d[0] = new Dozen();
d[1] = new Dozen();
d[2] = new Dozen();
then the arrays will be created.

Comment: @xelian But what does it have to do with this example? The question does not involve any method execution.

Comment: @Beri, yes does not but if you try you will understand that the Dozens object are not created and they are null.